# Puppet error: returned 1 instead of one of [0]

Tags: linux, ubuntu, puppet, vagrant

When using Puppet, I get error messages like

`returned 1 instead of one of [0]`

Is there a way to output/get the actual error message?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Sounds like you're dealing with an `exec` resource, right?

By default, the output of the command is logged by puppet in cases (like this one) that the command has failed - see the `logoutput` setting of the `exec` resource type.

If you're not seeing any other error output, it's possible the command simply didn't provide any (completely silent in both stdout and stderr); you may need to look into setting the application you're running into a more verbose mode.

Some applications return a non-zero exit code on success (though your `1` is almost certainly a failure of some kind).  To account for this, you can set `returns` to the set of exit codes that's expected on success; that's where the `[0]` in your error message comes from.

Setting this in your `exec` resource, for instance, would consider any of these three exit codes as a "successful" execution.

```
returns => [0, 2, 14]
```